# What do the following lines of code do in the context of sending Bitcoin?

Tags: segregated-witness, address-generation

I have recently started dev on Bitcoin and have a doubt regarding the following code. I have a dApp that prompts users to connect their BTC Wallet and in return, I get their address(testnet).

I want to understand this piece of code from this link
https://docs.xverse.app/sats-connect/creating-psbts

How do we get this **02818b7ff740a40f311d002123087053d5d9e0e1546674aedb10e15a5b57fd3985**

Given that we can only receive the address of the user which is in this format

**tb1q32vcpx59fucfc0jmd3hd3uqvpdwuq85j024qfl**

on the successful connection of the BTC wallet

Is there any way to convert the normal address to the long form of the address mentioned above?

```
const publicKey = hex.encode("02818b7ff740a40f311d002123087053d5d9e0e1546674aedb10e15a5b57fd3985")
const p2wpkh = btc.p2wpkh(publicKey, bitcoinTestnet);
const p2sh = btc.p2sh(p2wpkh, bitcoinTestnet);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot go from just the address to the wallet's public key. There is a hash step involved which is irreversible.

In the code example you're linking, this is not an issue, as it is code that is executed by the wallet *creating* the receive address. Obviously, they actually have the public key.

Comment: Can you explain me given the context how do I get the PSBT ?

Comment: You don't "get" the PSBT; you, as the spending wallet, which has all the information, creates it.